# While Automating JNLP Application, I am facing the below error

Tags: automation, jnlp

I'm facing an issue when trying to launch a JNLP (Java Network Launch Protocol) application using the Java Driver in my automation code. Here's a code snippet that I'm using:

```
import net.sourceforge.marathon.javadriver.JavaDriver;
import net.sourceforge.marathon.javadriver.JavaProfile; 

JavaProfile profile = new JavaProfile(JavaProfile.LaunchMode.JAVA_WEBSTART)

profile.setJNLPPath("C:\Users\spa6a5t\Music\frmservlet.jnlp");
profile.setJavaHome("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17");
Thread.sleep(10000);
profile.setStartWindowTitle("Oracle E-Business Suite R12");

JavaDriver driver = new JavaDriver(profile);
```

However, I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'WS631212', ip: '10.184.44.49'
Build info: version: '4.9.1', revision: 'eb2032df7f'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: net.sourceforge.marathon.javadriver.JavaDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: java, browserVersion: 1.0, platformName: any}]}]
Capabilities {browserName: java, browserVersion: 1.0, platformName: any}
It seems to be related to the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with 'void org.openqa.selenium.os.Command
```

I've verified my JNLP file path, Java home, and window title. Could anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully launch the JNLP application using the Java Driver?